# Can't change label text from another class

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to change the text of a label located in `Form1`, the form contain this:

```
Private Sub BKW_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BKW.DoWork

    MyFunction() ' This function is located in the class 'General function

End Sub
```

in the same `Form1` I also have:

```
 Private Delegate Sub UpdateLabelDel(ByVal txt As String)

Public Sub UpdateLabel(ByVal txt As String)
    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Invoke(New UpdateLabelDel(AddressOf UpdateLabel), txt)
    Else
        Label1.Text = txt
    End If
End Sub
```

in the `GeneralFunction` class I have this code for change the text label:

```
Dim frm As New Form1
frm.UpdateLabel("Starting function")
```

How you can see I call `MyFunction()` from `BackGroundWorker` called `BKW`, this function update the text using `.UpdateLabel` localted in Form1. The problem is that the `Label1` located in the same Form1 doesn't change any text, what is wrong?

Comment: Forget about background worker, does it work single threaded? If yes, please post your code without background worker, then ask about making it multi-threaded. If no, your problem is now simplified tenfold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This creates a *new form*:

```
Dim frm As New Form1
```

So you're not changing the text on the form that you see, you're changing it on an entirely separate form that you haven't displayed.

Instead, pass a reference to the current form to the code that needs it.  Something like this:

```
MyFunction(Me)
```

And the function signature would expect that reference, something like this:

```
Public Sub MyFunction(ByVal form As Form1)
```

And in that function you can reference the form instance from that variable:

```
form.UpdateLabel("Starting function")
```

Essentially, if you have code (classes, methods, etc.) which needs a reference to an object, the code which calls it should supply it with that reference.

Comment: Instead of passing `Me` I simply called the function by `Form1.UpdateLabel("some text")` but this also doesn't working.. I think that is the same thing nope?

Comment: @SalvatoreFucito: No, that's not the same thing.  That's attempting to call a *static* (`Shared` in VB) function on the `Form1` *class*, rather than trying to call an function on a *specific instance* of the class (the one being displayed to the user).

Comment: Seems working now, a lot of work for update a label text anyway